# How to strip html elements from string in nested list, Python

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I decided to use BeautifulSoup for extracting string integers from Pandas column. BeautifulSoup works well applied on a simple example, however, does not work for a list column in Pandas. I cannot find any mistake. Can you help?

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1":[["<span style='color: red;'>9</span>", "abcd"], ["a", "b, d"], ["a, b, z, x, y"], ["a, y","y, z, b"]], 
    "col2":[0, 1, 0, 1],
})

for list in df["col1"]:
    for item in list:
        if "span" in item:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(item, features = "lxml")
            item = soup.get_text()
        else:
            None  

print(df)
```

[image: This is what I get]

Desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "col1":[["9", "abcd"], ["a", "b, d"], ["a, b, z, x, y"], ["a, y","y, z, b"]], 
        "col2":[0, 1, 0, 1],
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate using a for loop on the Series, but when working with Pandas it's preferred and simpler to `apply` a function instead, like this:

```py
def extract_text(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for item in lst:
        if "span" in item:
            new_lst.append(BeautifulSoup(item, features="lxml").text)
        else:
            new_lst.append(item)
            
    return new_lst

df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(extract_text)
```

Or you could one-line it using list comprehension:

```py
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(
    lambda lst: [BeautifulSoup(item, features = "lxml").text if "span" in item else item for item in lst]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will apply the `extract_integer` function to each element of the `col1` column, replacing the original value with the extracted integer if the element contains the `"span"` tag, or leaving the value unchanged if it doesn't.

```py
def extract_integer(item):
    if "span" in item:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(item, features = "lxml")
        return soup.get_text()
    return item

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1":[["<span style='color: red;'>9</span>", "abcd"], ["a", "b, d"], ["a, b, z, x, y"], ["a, y","y, z, b"]], 
    "col2":[0, 1, 0, 1],
})

df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(lambda x: [extract_integer(item) for item in x])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
               col1  col2
0         [9, abcd]     0
1         [a, b, d]     1
2   [a, b, z, x, y]     0
3   [a, y, y, z, b]     1
```